# MSSQL Subselect in CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm struggling a little here.

I got a query to return some values based on a parameter. The parameters works as intended. They are provided by **MS SQL Reporting Services**.

This works as intenden:

```
SELECT 
T0.CardName
FROM OCRD T0 
WHERE
T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_CR) -- <-- MSSQL View
ORDER BY 
T0.[CardName]
```

So I thought, maybe try something like this:

```
SELECT 
T0.CardName
FROM OCRD T0 
WHERE
T0.[CardCode] IN (
CASE 
WHEN @VB = 'CR' THEN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_CR)
WHEN @VB = 'GR' THEN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_GR)
WHEN @VB = 'ZV' THEN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_ZV)
END)
ORDER BY 
T0.[Cardname]
```

I'm trying to provide named parameters like 'CR', 'ZV', 'GR' etc. In the background though, the expression should return a list of values. Thus the ... Carcode IN (...) statement.

I already know of workarounds on SSRS level like providing a list of values with checkboxes etc. but I'd like to have the user just choose one of the named parameters so they don't have to struggle with hundreds of results.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I chose [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48705804/3393877) to fit my needs the most as it had a neat explanation and suggestions on what I could do better.

```
WHERE (@VB = 'CR' AND T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_CR) ) OR
      (@VB = 'GR' AND T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_GR) ) OR
      (@VB = 'ZV' AND T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_ZV) )
```

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: Noted this in the comments in my answer, but where is `T2.[ItemCode]` coming from? You only have one object in your query `OCRD`; which you've for some reason given the alias `T0`. *(I hope you're not using increment integers to alias your tables...)* There is no object or alias `T2` in your sample query.

Comment: Ah sry! Reduced the query to a minimum. Ignore T2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not support boolean types or boolean expressions as a single value.  Instead, use basic boolean logic:

```
WHERE (@VB = 'CR' AND T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_CR) ) OR
      (@VB = 'GR' AND T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_GR) ) OR
      (@VB = 'ZV' AND T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_ZV) )
```

However, this is probably not the best solution.  You should probably be storing all the codes in one table with an appropriate "VB" value.  Then the logic would simply be:

```
T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode FROM USK_Codes c WHERE c.vb = @vb)
```

Having multiple tables with the same set of columns is usually a sign of a problem with the data model.

Comment: Yeah well, one problem here is more like "Please add something to do this and that with the customized report". It's a "grown" thing.
The other problem is, it's a list of customer codes where a specific employee is in charge. Those customes can change weekly. So a view was the easiest thing for me in this case (I think). Thanks however for your answer and a neat explanation!

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE (@VB = 'CR' and T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_CR))
   OR (@VB = 'GR' and T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_GR))
   OR (@VB = 'ZV' and T0.[CardCode] IN (SELECT cardcode from USK_Codes_ZV))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's exactly what Gordon suggests but I liked his explanation more so I chose his answer to be the chosen one.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a candidate for some dynamic SQL, depending on how many tables you really have with these Card Codes:

```
DECLARE @CardCode sysname = 'CR';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @SQL = N'
SELECT OCRD.CardName
FROM OCRD
WHERE OCRD.CardCode IN (SELECT sq.CardCode FROM ' + QUOTENAME(v.[name]) + N' sq)
ORDER BY OCRD.ItemCode;' --You reference T2 alias here, however, that isn't in yoru query, so where is it from...?
FROM sys.views v
WHERE v.[name] = N'USK_Codes_' + @CardCode;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it as a CTE with a union query on the card code tables.

```
WITH 
card_code_list  --you may want to make this a view
AS
(
  SELECT [VB] = 'CR', cardcode from USK_Codes_CR
  UNION SELECT [VB] = 'GR', cardcode from USK_Codes_GR
  UNION SELECT [VB] = 'ZV', cardcode from USK_Codes_ZV
)
SELECT 
  T0.CardName
FROM 
  OCRD T0 
  INNER JOIN card_code_list ccl ON T0.[CardCode] = ccl.[cardcode] AND ccl.[VB] = @VB
ORDER BY 
  T0.[Cardname]
```